# close chrome app with escape key

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

I'm trying to create a web app for Chrome and need help.
I want the app I made to close when the user presses the escape key (27) and don't know how to do that.

I have tried this piece of code I found but it doesn't work.

```
window.onload = function() {

$(document).keyup(function(e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key maps to keycode `27`
        window.close();
    }
});
```

}

Comment: Have you attached this function to the actual event like `keypress` or `keydown`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`window.close()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/close).

```
     var pressedKeyValue = keyEvent.keyCode;
     if(pressedKeyValue == 27)
     {
       window.close();
     }
```